# IE not displaying Image onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer

I got a Dropdown-List that calls "changeForm()" on the onChange-Event:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function changeForm() {
       document.getElementById('progressCircle').hidden = false;
       document.getElementById('ticketform').submit();

   }
```

This displays a normally hidden IMG-object (progressCircle) and submits the form directly after.

Now this works quite fine in Chrome, but IE does not seem to care about the image. It keeps hidden, while the submit() still is executed.

Any better Ideo how to solve that?

(This is part of an MVC-Page, if that does matter)

There are no errors in the browsers console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using this to display the image instead:

```
document.getElementById("progressCircle").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('ticketform').submit();
```

You can set the default state in your CSS like so:

```
#progressCircle {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a easier solution?

```
document.getElementById('ticketform').onsubmit = function() {
   document.body.className += ' loading';
};


body.loading #progressCircle{
   display:block;
}
```

> When  the form is submitted add the class 'loading' to the body
>
> In CSS when the body has the class loading show the `progressCircle`